# Unable to access GPIO pins as regular user despite being in dialout group

Tags: permissions

I'm running Ubuntu 21.04 on a Jetway JNP691-3350, and I need to access the GPIO pins.  I was, and still am, able to access the GPIO pins while running as root.  The research I've done suggested that I need to add the user to the dialout group.  After adding the user to the dialout group and rebooting, I'm still unable to access the GPIO pins as this user.  What is the next step in troubleshooting?